# Replacing values in a massive numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Good evening all, I'm really struggling with my code. I've made a 1D spectrum from a fits file. I've extracted the numerical values for each point along the file, but there are vertical lines of overexposed pixel values. I want to replace all values above 3000 with 0. This is what I've done so far:

```
import astropy as ap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from pathlib import Path
from astropy.nddata import CCDData
from ccdproc import ImageFileCollection
import ccdproc as ccdp
from os import listdir, walk
import astropy.units as u

# this function converts the class astropy.io.fits.hdulist.HDUList to a numpy array as ccd data

fitsfile = fits.open("img/HLXSpectrum.fits")
def spec(fitsfile):
    
    specList = fits.open("img/HLXSpectrum.fits", include_path=True)
    imgList = []
    for img in specList:
        ccd = CCDData(fitsfile[0].data, unit="adu")
        HLX = ccdp.trim_image(ccd, fits_section="[:2050, 480:840]")
        imgList.append(ccd)
        fitsfile.close()
    
    specImg = CCDData(ccd, unit="adu")
    return specImg
specImg = spec(fitsfile)

skyarray1 = specImg[180:220, 50:2045]
spectrum1 = np.array(skyarray1)

skyarray2 = specImg[220:260, 50:2045]
spectrum2 = np.array(skyarray2)

skyarray3 = specImg[140:180, 50:2045]
spectrum3 = np.array(skyarray3)

spectrumA = spectrum2 - spectrum3
spectrum = spectrumA - spectrum1

flux = []
pixel = []

fix = np.where(spectrum > 3000, spectrum, 0)

for i in range(len(fix[1])): # cropped img in x dimension
    flux.append(np.sum(skyarray1[:, i]))
    pixel.append(i)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16), dpi=800)
plt.plot(pixel, flux, color="red")
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.show()

# fig1.savefig("flux.png", dpi=800)
```

but no matter what I do, the image stays the same, even though the values in the arrays change. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes down to what you're plotting here:

```py
fix = np.where(spectrum > 3000, spectrum, 0)

for i in range(len(fix[1])): # cropped img in x dimension
    flux.append(np.sum(skyarray1[:, i]))
    pixel.append(i)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 16), dpi=800)
plt.plot(pixel, flux, color="red")
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

You're plotting `flux`, which is taking values from `skyarray1`, which has not been modified. I think you want to replace it with `fix` like this:

```py
for i in range(len(fix[1])): # cropped img in x dimension
    flux.append(np.sum(fix[:, i]))
    pixel.append(i)
```